# QGIS - graphically depict movement patterns

Tags: qgis, line, modelling

I want to make a graphical depiction in QGIS of two different datasets showing pedestrian movement patterns in a city center. One data set is observed, and the other is projected.

My data (CSV) consists of the following columns: 1. LinkID, 2. Pedestrians_Observed, 3. Pedestrians_projected

The LinkID column must be "connected" to a line layer I have in QGIS which covers the entire city center.

Ideally the graphical depiction should look something like this, in a way that makes it possible to visualize the differences between projected and the observed :

[image]

I am working in QGIS 3.4.13-Madeira.

Comment: So, you want to increase the thickness of a line based on the difference between Observed and Projected? You can use rule based symbology for that.